# Can I specify the loss function for GBM (or any ML algo) based on a subset of the population?

Tags: loss-function, lightgbm, gbm

I am trying to create a loss function for a GBM where I have two sub-populations, let's say divided by sex. Other than trying to predict actuals correctly, I also want to penalize if the model performs better on one sex than another. For example, I might be willing to sacrifice the overall performance of the model just to decrease the difference between the false negative rates of men vs. women. I found solutions for adding additional arguments to loss functions, but I couldn't find anything where I manipulate the loss function based on a feature of the underlying population. The label y_true, y_pred wouldn't include this information, so is there a way for me to feed this distinction? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manipulate the weights of the data, as described [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html) (in the "Weight Data" section). Assuming that you'd be working with LightGBM, apply the weight depending on the variable (e.g. if you want the loss for males to be worth half of the loss for females) in following way (code in Python):

```py
weights = pd.Series(index = ['male', 'female'], data = [0.5, 1])
train_weights = X_train.Gender.replace('male',weights.loc['male']).replace('female',weights.loc['female'])
test_weights = X_test.Gender.replace('male',weights.loc['male']).replace('female',weights.loc['female'])

model = LGBMClassifier()
model.fit(X = X_train, y = y_train, sample_weight = train_weights,
          eval_set = (X_test, y_test), eval_sample_weight = [test_weights])
```

You can find more about it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2549), with links to previous discussions.